# DFM Layout Issue in Delphi XE4 RAD Studio

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I have a code in Delphi 7 application. When I open it in Delphi XE4 and afterwards when I compare the both codes in SVN, I notice that all the dfm files have been changed. The changes which I notice is like:

```
Width = 443 --changed in Delphi XE4
Height = 277 --changed in Delphi XE4
ExplicitWidth = 443 --added automatically in Delphi XE4
ExplicitHeight = 277 --added automatically in Delphi XE4
```

How should I handle this unexpected behavior of RAD Studio?

Comment: [`Let it be`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2476690/960757)... ;-)

Comment: @TLama - but its causing problems to me. Suppose I have changed only 2-3 lines in dfm file which already contains 3000 lines. When I open to compare it, instead of 2-3 lines change, I am seeing 300 lines change. Is there no solution of this kind of problem?

Comment: Similar question, [`Is there a Delphi option to 'lock' the design (layout) of a form against accidental changes?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5486957/576719).

Comment: Commit the change to your VCS and you'll see no change. Those `Explicit...` properties are added just when you open the form with no change for the first time as far as I know.

Comment: You can also configure your diff viewer to ignore these lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to suppress the generation of those properties in the .dfm you can use Andy Hausladen's DDevExtensions tool.

Personally, I think you may be better off accepting this new reality and admitting those changes into your reply once and for all. Sometimes it's easier to go along with a change like this rather than fighting it.

Comment: Would have been an option if even now Delphi would not add/remove those at random, garbling the repo history.